# Prime Number using GOTO statement in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is my code for Prime Number using goto statement

```
set serveroutput on;
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2  msg varchar2 (30);
  3  n pls_integer := 83;
  4
  5  begin
  6  for i in 2..round( sqrt(n) ) loop
  7  if n mod i=0 then
  8  msg := ' is not a prime number';
  9  goto when_prime;
 10  end if;
 11  end loop;
 12
 13  msg := ' is a prime number';
 14
 15  <>
 16  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(n) || msg);
 17  end;
 18  /
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
<>
*
ERROR at line 15:
ORA-06550: line 15, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following:
( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
<an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
<a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
merge pipe purge
ORA-06550: line 16, column 40:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
. ( ) , * % & - + / at mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)>
and or || multiset
```

I want to check prime number or not a prime number using goto statement

Comment: What is represented by `<>`?

Comment: Yay for `goto`! Welcome to [the campaign for Transgressive Programming](https://radiofreetooting.blogspot.com/2012/12/gotos-considered.html).

Answer (score 3):

You are not properly declaring the `when_prime` label.

Just replace this:

```
<>
```

With:

```
<<when_prime>>
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9d2f3fbe572585d703ccae2cb4db3cd0)**:

```
dbms_output:
83 is a prime number
```

Answer (score 0):

You misused the label declaration section, it should be wrapped in `<< >>` and not `< >`

Your code should be something like this:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      MSG   VARCHAR2(30);
  3      N     PLS_INTEGER := 83;
  4  BEGIN
  5      FOR I IN 2..ROUND(SQRT(N)) LOOP
  6          IF N MOD I = 0 THEN
  7              MSG := ' is not a prime number';
  8              GOTO WHEN_PRIME;
  9          END IF;
 10      END LOOP;
 11
 12      MSG := ' is a prime number';
 13      << WHEN_PRIME >>
 14      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(N) || MSG);
 15  END;
 16  /
83 is a prime number

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**UPDATE - Important**

May be irrelevant for the error you are getting but you can directly use the following query to find the prime number:

```
SQL> WITH NUMBR AS (SELECT 83 NUMBR FROM DUAL)
  2  SELECT NUMBR,
  3         CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN MOD(NUMBR, LEVEL) = 0
  4                       THEN 1 END) = 1
  5              THEN 'prime'
  6              ELSE 'not prime'
  7        END AS "Prime?"
  8  FROM NUMBR
  9  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= FLOOR(NUMBR / 2)
 10  GROUP BY NUMBR;

     NUMBR Prime?
---------- ---------
        83 prime

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Appreciate the second option you gave for Prime Number but I have to implement the Goto statement